# How to remove last characters combination of letters with space in file name

Tags: terminal

In terminal, I'm trying to rename all files in the folder that has a combination of a space and numbers at the end of the file name. The end of the filename has a combination of a space and numbers (for example, " 12334") and I need any numbers and a space right before .mp3 deleted.

For example:

- `filename 1234567.mp3`
- `my file 123.mp3`
- `your file 98.mp3`

Renamed to:

- `filename.mp3`
- `my file.mp3`
- `your file.mp3`

Comment: what if the filename is `file name 123.mp3`?

Comment: then it would renamed as file name.mp3

Comment: the end of the filename has a combination of a space and a number (for example, " 12334") and I need those deleted. Any files that has that same combination right before .mp3 should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash

```bsh
$ touch 'filename 1234567.mp3' 'my file 123.mp3' 'your file 98.mp3' 1234.mp3 zzz.mp3

$ for f in *.mp3; do
    g=${f%%[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]).mp3}
    if [[ $f != $g ]]; then
        mv -v -- "$f" "$g.mp3"
    fi
done
renamed 'filename 1234567.mp3' -> 'filename.mp3'
renamed 'my file 123.mp3' -> 'my file.mp3'
renamed 'your file 98.mp3' -> 'your file.mp3'

$ ls
1234.mp3   filename.mp3  'my file.mp3'  'your file.mp3'   zzz.mp3
```

This uses bash's [*extended* patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) to match a space followed by 1 or more digits followed by ".mp3" at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

First, mark the `zmv` function for autoloading (best in `~/.zshrc` if you're going to use that often):

```
autoload -Uz zmv
```

Then:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)( *)(.mp3)' '$1$2$4'
```

Remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

To rename the files only if the part after the last space is a sequence of decimal digits:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)( <->)(.mp3)' '$1$2$4'
```

(or `<98-1234567>` in place of `<->` for only numbers in that range).

The `(**/)` matches any level of subdirectories. If it's only the files in the current directory you want to rename, then it's just:

```
zmv -n '(*)( *)(.mp3)' '$1$3'
```

Comment: Never mind I forgot you said to remove -n. It worked Thank you so much! ;)